# How to setup a csv-file to import image-paths into an image-field via Feeds-module?

Tags: 7, feeds, media, importing-exporting

I import a csv-file via Feeds-module and got stuck with the images for a node. All the other fields are importet as wanted, except the path for the image-field.
The images are already uploaded to the directory below...

An example for a row value of a path:
sites/all/default/files/images/name.JPG

After the import, the image field is just empty:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the full HTTP path. It's possible that something like a file schema might work (`public://images/name.JPG`), but in my extensive use with Feeds we import file fields (mostly images but also mp3, pdf, etc) by specifying the full HTTP path that the file can be found at, e.g.: `http://example.com/sites/default/files/images/name.JPG`.

Comment: Not working here. I don't know where the glitch is on my side. I tried several times, with and without the http:, tried other field types (file) ...but no luck. Any idea how to debug this? The other fields are working... it must be something really stupid that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Are you positive that your server can wget the URL you have specified in the cell? Are you seeing any errors? Turn on debugging for the feed importer and check the feed importer's log.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with wget. Do you mean if the actual directory is accessible, then yes. If i upload an image for the content type manually, and try to access this image with the full path in the browser, that's working.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for the Images folder? I have done many image imports successfully with the format public://images/subfolder/imagename.jpg. Also, check your path. In your post you state "sites/all/default/files" which is unusual (and perhaps just a typo here). Default is "sites/default/files"

Comment: You're right with the path, which was a typo indeed. But it's still not working. I'll see if i can get into drush and setup the hidden debugger (http://drupal.org/node/1189894) tomorrow. My heads spinning and it late over here... will get back to you guys. Thanks for your help...

Comment: Coincidentally, I've just run some importers locally to test importing from both CSV and JSON files before I do the same on production. They both had mp3 files referenced via HTTP and things worked as expected. Your PHP environment will need curl support and they recommend 5.2+.

Comment: Yay! I finally got it workin'! After checking everything again and again i found the bastard in the csv itself. I use tabs as separators and somehow i got an extra tab before the path... *gnarl* ;) Thanks a lot for your hints and help. I learned something...

Comment: confirming that drupal file system paths (`public://dir/image.jpg`) work fine

Comment: You must also pay attention to the permissions of the file being imported and the directory specified by the file field.  Drupal needs to be able to read in the file and write the import file to the file destination path.  If import & destination are the same, the import file will need to be writable by the apache user.

Comment: @doublejack in the public://dir/image.jpg //dir is relative to drupal dir or absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

For local path, what worked for me was putting the file under sites/default/files of the drupal project it is in. The value of import file would **public://filename.ext**